# cosine Elliptic Integral with an indeterminate answer

Tags: integration, elliptic-integrals

I am trying to solve:
$$\int_a^b\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-(A-\cos(Bx))^2}}.$$ I have first tried to use the substitution $u=\tan(x/2)$ then after simplifying $v=\sqrt{\frac{A}{A+2}}\tan(u)$, this gives an elliptic function, but then when I evaluate with $a=0$ and $b=\frac{1}{B}\arccos(A-1)$ it gives an indeterminate answer.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Let $Bx=t$ to make the integral
$$J= B\,I=\int_0^{k \cos ^{-1}(A-1)}\frac{dt}{\sqrt{1-(A-\cos (t))^2}}$$ where $0\leq A\leq 2$ and where "hope" to make $k \to 1$.

For the antiderivative, we face the elliptic integral which for $t=0$ gives $0$. Then, the only problem is at the upper bound where we *seem* to face a serious problem of the type $\frac 00$ when $k \to 1$.

Using L'Hospital rule six times did not solve the problem.

Looking in more details at the series expansions of both numerator and denominator show that they both are polynomials in $\sqrt{k-1}$ without constant term. However, for the numerator, the first term remains undefined !

Then, I used brute force and showed that for $k=1-\epsilon$, the calculations work nicely.

Working with illimited precision, I have been able to use $\epsilon=10^{-48}$ and compared with numerical integration with $k=1$.
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 A & \text{using } k=1-10^{-48} & \text{numerical integration} \\
 0.1 & 4.384143232 & 4.384143271 \\
 0.2 & 3.695637363 & 3.695636872 \\
 0.3 & 3.296411566 & 3.296411602 \\
 0.4 & 3.016112492 & 3.016112507 \\
 0.5 & 2.801206085 & 2.801206087 \\
 0.6 & 2.627773332 & 2.627773333 \\
 0.7 & 2.483014115 & 2.483014115 \\
 0.8 & 2.359263555 & 2.359263555 \\
 0.9 & 2.251562589 & 2.251562589 \\
 1.0 & 2.156515647 & 2.156515648 \\
 1.1 & 2.071694646 & 2.071694646 \\
 1.2 & 1.995302778 & 1.995302778 \\
 1.3 & 1.925972938 & 1.925972938 \\
 1.4 & 1.862640802 & 1.862640802 \\
 1.5 & 1.804461622 & 1.804461622 \\
 1.6 & 1.750753803 & 1.750753803 \\
 1.7 & 1.700959543 & 1.700959543 \\
 1.8 & 1.654616668 & 1.654616668 \\
 1.9 & 1.611338059 & 1.611338059
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: We can find a linear transformation s.t.
$$(1 - u^2) (1 - (a - u)^2) =
C (1 - t^2) (1 - m t^2),$$
then the integral becomes $K(m)$.

Comment: @Maxim. Make an answer of it ! Thanks for the point. Cheers :-)

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the addition comment, I will try and work something out!

Comment: @Maxim when you say linear transformation do you mean non-linear? As in, $t=\arccos(u)$? This would then reduce the integral $J$ to $J'=\int_{A-1}^1\frac{du}{\sqrt{1-u^2}\sqrt{1-(A-u)^2}}$. Then with a linear change of variables $x=u-A+1$ then integral reduces to $J''=\int_0^A\frac{du}{\sqrt{1-(x+A-1)^2}\sqrt{1-(1-x)^2}}$. Is this the kind of thing you were thinking?